# how can I do manually , without the following make file?

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I have the following make file, which runs perfectly:

```
CFLAGS=-O2 -g -Wall 
RANLIB=ranlib

all: test libeasyperf.a

libeasyperf.a: easyperf.o
    $(AR) rc $@ $^
    $(RANLIB) $@

test: easyperf.o test.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -lm

clean:
    rm -f *.o test libeasyperf.a
```

Can we rewrite the make file without `ranlib` and archive (`ar`) things. Actually I want to run `./test` by manually compiling each file (`easyperf.c`, `test.c`) without Makefile doing all these.

Is it possible?

Comment: Make outputs the command it is about to run before doing it. You could have just copied those lines.

Comment: yes. you are right! @ZanLynx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -O2 -g -Wall -c test.c -o test.o
gcc -O2 -g -Wall -c easyperf.c -o easyperf.o
gcc -O2 -g -o test easyperf.o test.o -lm
./test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -O2 -g -Wall test.c easyperf.c -o test -lm
./test
```